# Team Foundation Server 2013 Express is hung and can't stop it

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've got a small MVC project I've been working on, which I keep in Team Foundation Server 2013 Express on my PC. I've been trying to open it for the last 30+ minutes. All of 89 files. TFS is hung and has been hung, the whole time. Finally I tried to cancel that operation. But that's failing too. Now I can't do anything with Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2013, etc. I've taken a look at task manager and VS 2013 really isn't taking up much resources, so what could be wrong? I'd really rather not reboot my machine while this stuff is going on, but at some point I'm going to have to if this is so hung that it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I would do is bounce my machene. You will not loose anything as the files are all local as well.

Then check that the web access comes back up. If it does then try checking in again.

I would recommend that you take a free account on http://tfs.visualstudio.com and move all of your code there. It's much more resilient than running locally and is backed up. Even better would be to create a team project with Git giving you full offline access as well.